# store elements of a list in some other list python

Tags: python

Suppose I have:

```
storage = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1]
```

I want to store these elements in some other list such as the first position of that list contains first three elements of storage, second contains next three, third contains next three and so on and so forth.

Actually I have 4891695 elements in a list. I want to store first 2000 at 1st position, next 2000 at second position and so on and so forth.

Comment: @DonkeyKong you are a possible duplicate

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Sorry?